# is this valid javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, but is this valid?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (condition()) { 
        location = "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz"; 
    } 

function condition()
{
if(something)
return true
else
return false
</script>
```

I am trying to write a javascript that goes insdie of content editer web part inside of SharePoint.
Thanks.

Comment: You tried it and decided it was (or wasn't) valid because \_\_\_\_?

Comment: I don't think SO should be used as spell check for your JavaScript. There is no question here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *almost* valid (needs a closing  `}`), you can call a function in or as an `if()` condition.

It should have the `}` on the end:

```
function condition() {
  if(something)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

Or much simpler:

```
function condition() {
  return something;
}
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QDLP8/).

Answer (score 1):

No, your missing a } at the end of your condition function.

Answer (score 0):

No, but this is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    if (condition()) { 
        location = "http://example.com/foo/bar/baz"; 
    } 

function condition()
{
  if(something)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, You need a closing curly bracket on your function.